# What does ::new mean?

Tags: c++, new-operator, scope-resolution

When examining the MS directX 11 DXUT example, the following code appeared:

```
template<typename TYPE> HRESULT CGrowableArray <TYPE>::SetSize( int nNewMaxSize )
{
int nOldSize = m_nSize;

if( nOldSize > nNewMaxSize )
{
    assert( m_pData );
    if( m_pData )
    {
        // Removing elements. Call dtor.

        for( int i = nNewMaxSize; i < nOldSize; ++i )
            m_pData[i].~TYPE();
    }
}

// Adjust buffer.  Note that there's no need to check for error
// since if it happens, nOldSize == nNewMaxSize will be true.)
HRESULT hr = SetSizeInternal( nNewMaxSize );

if( nOldSize < nNewMaxSize )
{
    assert( m_pData );
    if( m_pData )
    {
        // Adding elements. Call ctor.

        for( int i = nOldSize; i < nNewMaxSize; ++i )
            ::new ( &m_pData[i] ) TYPE;
    }
}

return hr;
}
```

This can be found in DXUTmisc.h on line 428 on my version of DXSDK (June2010). I'm wondering about that **::new** thing....I'm trying to Google and search on stack overflow but seems the searching engine is discarding the two colons when I type "::new" in the search bar....

Comment: `::` is the [scope resolution operator](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scope_resolution_operator) and by itself it specifies the global scope. It makes sure that `new` is called from the global scope.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

The `::new` call means that the program is trying to use the global `new` operator to allocate space, rather than using any `new` operator that was defined at class or namespace scope.  In particular, this code is trying to use something called *[placement `new`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Placement_syntax)* in which the object being created is placed at a specific location in memory.  By explicitly calling back up into the global scope, the function ensures that this correctly uses placement new and doesn't accidentally call a different allocation function introduced somewhere in the scope chain.

Hope this helps!

Comment: +1 for pointing out the XY question.  (They asked X, but really needed to know Y)

Comment: +1 for point out the placement new. I should have noticed this.

Comment: Thanks, I think its mainly an issue with the placement new. The actual memory allocation is done on the line of **SetSizeInternal()** with a realloc call. So the new here is really just to call **TYPE**'s constructor, if any.

Comment: And what does TYPE mean? (i.e `::new (&x) int`) what does the int do?

Comment: @David- Here, `TYPE` is a template parameter indicating what type of objects are being stored.  The line `::new (&x) int` means "construct an object of type `int` at the memory location referred to by the pointer `&x`.

Answer (score 3):

::new ensures the new operator at global, i.e. standard new operator, is called. Note :: before new indicates global scope.