# new / delete mismatch

Tags: c++, crash, libraries, new-operator, delete-operator

In my library (which replace global `new`/`delete` operators), I use another external library *(casablanca pplx)*.
This external library doesn't include the replaced `new`/`delete` operators (I checked by using the show includes option of Visual studio).

Some objects of this external library *(like streams or exceptions)* are created by using the default `new[]` operator *(which calls my replaced `new` operator)*, and are destroyed by using the default `delete[]` operator *(which doesn't call my replaced `delete` operator)*. This results in a **general protection fault**.

What can explain that behavior?

*I use Visual Studio 2012.*

Example source code (get google.fr by using the casablanca http client):

```
web::http::client::http_client_config config;
config.set_timeout(std::chrono::seconds(10));
utility::string_t uri = L"http://www.google.fr";
web::http::client::http_client client(uri, config);
web::http::http_request request(web::http::methods::GET);

client.request(request).then([uri](web::http::http_response response ) {
    unsigned short statusCode = response.status_code();
    if (statusCode == 200)
    {
        concurrency::streams::stringstreambuf stream;
        return response.body().read_to_end(stream).then([stream](size_t) {
            std::string responseText = stream.collection();
        }); // crash here (stream destructor)
    }
});
```

New callstack :

```
Application64_d.dll!operator new(unsigned __int64 iSize) Line 262   C++ // My replaced new operator
Application64_d.dll!operator new[](unsigned __int64 count) Line 7   C++ // C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 11.0\VC\crt\src\newaop.cpp
Application64_d.dll!Concurrency::streams::details::basic_producer_consumer_buffer<unsigned char>::_block::_block(unsigned __int64 size) Line 437    C++
Application64_d.dll!std::_Ref_count_obj<Concurrency::streams::details::basic_producer_consumer_buffer<unsigned char>::_block>::_Ref_count_obj<Concurrency::streams::details::basic_producer_consumer_buffer<unsigned char>::_block><unsigned __int64 & __ptr64>(unsigned __int64 & _V0) Line 873    C++
Application64_d.dll!std::make_shared<Concurrency::streams::details::basic_producer_consumer_buffer<unsigned char>::_block,unsigned __int64 & __ptr64>(unsigned __int64 & _V0) Line 972  C++
Application64_d.dll!Concurrency::streams::details::basic_producer_consumer_buffer<unsigned char>::_alloc(unsigned __int64 count) Line 165   C++
Application64_d.dll!Concurrency::streams::details::streambuf_state_manager<unsigned char>::alloc(unsigned __int64 count) Line 651   C++
Application64_d.dll!Concurrency::streams::streambuf<unsigned char>::alloc(unsigned __int64 count) Line 993  C++
Application64_d.dll!web::http::client::details::winhttp_client::completion_callback(void * hRequestHandle, unsigned __int64 context, unsigned long statusCode, void * statusInfo, unsigned long statusInfoLength) Line 1167 C++
winhttp.dll!00007ff83259db67()  Unknown
winhttp.dll!00007ff83259d87a()  Unknown
winhttp.dll!00007ff832599fe5()  Unknown
Application64_d.dll!web::http::client::details::winhttp_client::read_next_response_chunk(web::http::client::details::winhttp_request_context * pContext, unsigned long bytesRead, bool firstRead) Line 693  C++
Application64_d.dll!web::http::client::details::winhttp_client::completion_callback(void * hRequestHandle, unsigned __int64 context, unsigned long statusCode, void * statusInfo, unsigned long statusInfoLength) Line 1156 C++
winhttp.dll!00007ff83259db67()  Unknown
winhttp.dll!00007ff8325c653d()  Unknown
Application64_d.dll!web::http::client::details::winhttp_client::completion_callback(void * hRequestHandle, unsigned __int64 context, unsigned long statusCode, void * statusInfo, unsigned long statusInfoLength) Line 1051 C++
winhttp.dll!00007ff83259db67()  Unknown
winhttp.dll!00007ff8325a20b7()  Unknown
winhttp.dll!00007ff8325958a0()  Unknown
winhttp.dll!00007ff832594699()  Unknown
ntdll.dll!00007ff839723021()    Unknown
ntdll.dll!00007ff839721989()    Unknown
kernel32.dll!00007ff8392c2774() Unknown
ntdll.dll!00007ff839750d51()    Unknown
```

Delete callstack :

```
msvcr110d.dll!operator delete(void * pUserData) Line 52 C++ // C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 11.0\VC\crt\src\dbgdel.cpp
msvcr110d.dll!operator delete[](void * p) Line 22   C++ // C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 11.0\VC\crt\src\delete2.cpp
Application64_d.dll!Concurrency::streams::details::basic_producer_consumer_buffer<unsigned char>::_block::~_block() Line 443    C++
Application64_d.dll!Concurrency::streams::details::basic_producer_consumer_buffer<unsigned char>::_block::`scalar deleting destructor'(unsigned int)    C++
Application64_d.dll!std::_Ref_count_obj<Concurrency::streams::details::basic_producer_consumer_buffer<unsigned char>::_block>::_Destroy() Line 885  C++
Application64_d.dll!std::_Ref_count_base::_Decref() Line 121    C++
Application64_d.dll!std::_Ptr_base<Concurrency::streams::details::basic_producer_consumer_buffer<unsigned char>::_block>::_Decref() Line 347    C++
Application64_d.dll!std::shared_ptr<Concurrency::streams::details::basic_producer_consumer_buffer<unsigned char>::_block>::~shared_ptr<Concurrency::streams::details::basic_producer_consumer_buffer<unsigned char>::_block>() Line 624 C++
Application64_d.dll!std::shared_ptr<Concurrency::streams::details::basic_producer_consumer_buffer<unsigned char>::_block>::`scalar deleting destructor'(unsigned int)   C++
Application64_d.dll!std::allocator<std::shared_ptr<Concurrency::streams::details::basic_producer_consumer_buffer<unsigned char>::_block> >::destroy<std::shared_ptr<Concurrency::streams::details::basic_producer_consumer_buffer<unsigned char>::_block> >(std::shared_ptr<Concurrency::streams::details::basic_producer_consumer_buffer<unsigned char>::_block> * _Ptr) Line 624  C++
Application64_d.dll!std::allocator_traits<std::allocator<std::shared_ptr<Concurrency::streams::details::basic_producer_consumer_buffer<unsigned char>::_block> > >::destroy<std::shared_ptr<Concurrency::streams::details::basic_producer_consumer_buffer<unsigned char>::_block> >(std::allocator<std::shared_ptr<Concurrency::streams::details::basic_producer_consumer_buffer<unsigned char>::_block> > & _Al, std::shared_ptr<Concurrency::streams::details::basic_producer_consumer_buffer<unsigned char>::_block> * _Ptr) Line 758    C++
Application64_d.dll!std::_Wrap_alloc<std::allocator<std::shared_ptr<Concurrency::streams::details::basic_producer_consumer_buffer<unsigned char>::_block> > >::destroy<std::shared_ptr<Concurrency::streams::details::basic_producer_consumer_buffer<unsigned char>::_block> >(std::shared_ptr<Concurrency::streams::details::basic_producer_consumer_buffer<unsigned char>::_block> * _Ptr) Line 910   C++
Application64_d.dll!std::deque<std::shared_ptr<Concurrency::streams::details::basic_producer_consumer_buffer<unsigned char>::_block>,std::allocator<std::shared_ptr<Concurrency::streams::details::basic_producer_consumer_buffer<unsigned char>::_block> > >::pop_front() Line 1476    C++
Application64_d.dll!Concurrency::streams::details::basic_producer_consumer_buffer<unsigned char>::update_read_head(unsigned __int64 count) Line 644 C++
Application64_d.dll!Concurrency::streams::details::basic_producer_consumer_buffer<unsigned char>::read(unsigned char * ptr, unsigned __int64 count, bool advance) Line 620  C++
Application64_d.dll!<lambda_1f1656160f66eb3ff369c30cc6352caf>::operator()() Line 279    C++
Application64_d.dll!std::_Callable_obj<<lambda_1f1656160f66eb3ff369c30cc6352caf>,0>::_ApplyX<void>() Line 431   C++
Application64_d.dll!std::_Func_impl<std::_Callable_obj<<lambda_1f1656160f66eb3ff369c30cc6352caf>,0>,std::allocator<std::_Func_class<void,std::_Nil,std::_Nil,std::_Nil,std::_Nil,std::_Nil,std::_Nil,std::_Nil> >,void,std::_Nil,std::_Nil,std::_Nil,std::_Nil,std::_Nil,std::_Nil,std::_Nil>::_Do_call() Line 239  C++
Application64_d.dll!std::_Func_class<void,std::_Nil,std::_Nil,std::_Nil,std::_Nil,std::_Nil,std::_Nil,std::_Nil>::operator()() Line 514 C++
Application64_d.dll!Concurrency::streams::details::basic_producer_consumer_buffer<unsigned char>::_request::complete() Line 543 C++
Application64_d.dll!Concurrency::streams::details::basic_producer_consumer_buffer<unsigned char>::fulfill_outstanding() Line 424    C++
Application64_d.dll!Concurrency::streams::details::basic_producer_consumer_buffer<unsigned char>::_close_write() Line 360   C++
Application64_d.dll!Concurrency::streams::details::streambuf_state_manager<unsigned char>::close(int mode) Line 413 C++
Application64_d.dll!Concurrency::streams::streambuf<unsigned char>::close(int mode) Line 960    C++
Application64_d.dll!Concurrency::streams::basic_ostream<unsigned char>::close() Line 151    C++
Application64_d.dll!web::http::details::http_msg_base::_complete(unsigned __int64 body_size, const std::exception_ptr & exceptionPtr) Line 181  C++
Application64_d.dll!web::http::client::details::request_context::complete_request(unsigned __int64 body_size) Line 119  C++
Application64_d.dll!web::http::client::details::winhttp_client::completion_callback(void * hRequestHandle, unsigned __int64 context, unsigned long statusCode, void * statusInfo, unsigned long statusInfoLength) Line 1194 C++
winhttp.dll!00007ff83259db67()  Unknown
winhttp.dll!00007ff83259d87a()  Unknown
winhttp.dll!00007ff832599fe5()  Unknown
Application64_d.dll!web::http::client::details::winhttp_client::read_next_response_chunk(web::http::client::details::winhttp_request_context * pContext, unsigned long bytesRead, bool firstRead) Line 693  C++
Application64_d.dll!web::http::client::details::winhttp_client::completion_callback(void * hRequestHandle, unsigned __int64 context, unsigned long statusCode, void * statusInfo, unsigned long statusInfoLength) Line 1231 C++
winhttp.dll!00007ff83259b6aa()  Unknown
Application64_d.dll!web::http::client::details::winhttp_client::completion_callback(void * hRequestHandle, unsigned __int64 context, unsigned long statusCode, void * statusInfo, unsigned long statusInfoLength) Line 1174 C++
winhttp.dll!00007ff83259db67()  Unknown
winhttp.dll!00007ff8325955e7()  Unknown
winhttp.dll!00007ff832594699()  Unknown
ntdll.dll!00007ff839723021()    Unknown
ntdll.dll!00007ff839721989()    Unknown
kernel32.dll!00007ff8392c2774() Unknown
ntdll.dll!00007ff839750d51()    Unknown
```

new and delete operators :

```
inline void* operator new (::size_t size);
inline void operator delete (void* ptr);
inline void* operator new[] (::size_t size);
inline void operator delete[] (void* ptr);
```

Comment: If you check the call stack of the crash, you can check out the runtime delete operator's signature. Maybe you haven't overridden all possible new/delete functions.

Comment: Yes I added the callstacks. And I added the files of new and delete calls. I don't understand why the custom new is called, and the custom delete not.

I guess the runtime new op is compiled in my application (in my Application64_d.dll), but why the runtime delete op not?

Comment: Have you overridden `delete[]`?

Comment: Yes i updated the post

Comment: Should I be surprised the custom new op is called? Or the custom delete op is not called?

Comment: Maybe it is because they're inline? What happens if you remove inline?

Comment: Maybe the library you are using is inconsistently using `new`, `::new`, `delete` and `::delete`. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14147029/what-does-new-mean

Comment: I don't think so. Here is the accused class : https://github.com/Microsoft/cpprestsdk/blob/master/Release/include/cpprest/producerconsumerstream.h#L419 and particuliary the `m_data` member

Comment: As you can see, this library (cpprestsdk) is massively templated. But my source code when I use this library doesn't include my custom new/delete operators.

Comment: @geza The use of inline keyword changes the behavior for `new[]` and `delete[]` (No changes for `new` and `delete`). And there is a bug in Visual Studio 2013 *(and older)* on default new/delete operators compilation behaviors. Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Visual Studio 2013 *(and older)*, the default `delete[]` operator is not built in the binary of the application *(as opposed to the default `new`, `new[]` and `delete` operators)*. It is called directly from msvcr110d.dll.

When the **inline** keyword is used, the replaced `new[]` and `delete[]` operators are not used as default in the whole application *(as opposed to the `new` and `delete` operators)* unless we explicitly include the header.
So the default `new[]` operator *(built in the binary of the application)* calls the replaced `new` operator.
But the default `delete[]` operator *(called directly from msvcr110d.dll)* doesn't find the replaced `delete` operator and use the default `delete` operator *(from msvcr110d.dll)*.

For my solution, I removed the **inline** keyword and put the operators in a source file.
This bug has been fixed and should not appear in Visual Studio 2015 *(and newer)*.