# What is the difference between new and ::new

Tags: c++

Many libraries like boost use `::new` and `::delete` .

Example from `boost::make_shared`

```
template< class T, class... Args > typename boost::detail::sp_if_not_array< T >::type make_shared( Args && ... args )
{
    boost::shared_ptr< T > pt( static_cast< T* >( 0 ), BOOST_SP_MSD( T ) );

    boost::detail::sp_ms_deleter< T > * pd = static_cast<boost::detail::sp_ms_deleter< T > *>( pt._internal_get_untyped_deleter() );

    void * pv = pd->address();

    ::new( pv ) T( boost::detail::sp_forward<Args>( args )... );
    pd->set_initialized();

    T * pt2 = static_cast< T* >( pv );

    boost::detail::sp_enable_shared_from_this( &pt, pt2, pt2 );
    return boost::shared_ptr< T >( pt, pt2 );
}
```

What does this mean? and why would one use `::new` over just new?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What does ::new mean?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14147029/what-does-new-mean)

Answer (score 42, accepted):

A class `C`  could define its own [`operator new`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/new/operator_new) (this enables, for example, to have your own allocation policy for that class, and/or to provide some [Allocator](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/concept/Allocator) for it. Many standard [containers](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container) templates accept an optional allocator argument, for example the second argument to [`std::vector`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector); see also [`std::allocator`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/allocator) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8019003/841108) example).

If you code `new C`, that operator would be used (if it exists).

If you code `::new C`, the global `new` is used

Your example is using the global [placement `new`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/new)

Answer (score 21):

`new`, `new[]`, `delete`, and `delete[]` (including the placement variants) are overridable *both* at `class` *and* at global scope, although doing the latter is ill-advised.

When you see `::new`, you are using the global `new` operator.

Comment: The global placement new, which is not displacable by the application, unlike the other global functions (thankfully). This is essentially defense against the dark arts.

Comment: is the new and ::new same when used in global scope?

Comment: @EduardRostomyan: Absolutely!

Comment: @EduardRostomyan No: `new X` will prefer an `operator new` function defined in `class X` itself, or a base class of `X` or a namespace containing `X`.  `::new X` will only use the global `::operator new` function.

Answer (score 6):

In general whenever scope resolution ( `::`)operator is used without any specifier at LHS, it refers to the global scope. Here also it is same.

Coming to the operator `new`, it can be overloaded at local and outer scope. Hence to access the global variant scope resolution operator is used.

Answer (score 2):

`new` can be overriden and replaced.  So simply stating `new` won't always get the `new` you want.

In this specific case, we are looking at placement new:

```
void * pv = pd->address();

::new( pv ) T( boost::detail::sp_forward<Args>( args )... );
```

this is where we are trying to construct a `T` in the location `pv`.

To avoid the possibility that overrids of `new` are invoked instead of the "real" placement `new`, you have to use `::new( void pointer here ) type( arguments... );`.  That specific `new` can neither be replaced nor overridden.

Comment: Can it not? Practically speaking it usually can - most c++ runtimes provide a static library and as c++ does not prevent you defining your own global operator new you can effectively replace the built in implementation most of the time. In terms of the c++ spec it probably falls into 'undefined/implementation defined' behaviour.

Comment: The last paragraph sounds like (the usual `void*`) placement new is a drop-in replacement for plain `new` just to avoid using a different or replaceable `operator new`, but they have rather different behavior: Plain `new` allocates memory for you, but placement new requires some already valid region of memory.

Comment: @ChrisBecke The C++ spec does define a number of requirements on any user-defined replacement of global `operator new` to make sure it stays mostly sane. If those are disobeyed, yes, you have undefined behavior.

Answer (score -1):

The normal new operator is implemented at the class scale and can be overriden while ::new is implemented in a global scale and can't be overriden.